# Display all custom attributes Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm working on a project where I want to display product's image and customs attributes from Woocommerce.

I already set attributes like this

[image]

I want in my php code display all the attributes (title et terms).

I already try `<?php $product->list_attributes(); ?>`. It works fine but data are displaying in `<table>`. I want to customize the display.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I get stuck with a custom method like this in WooCommerce, I try to resort to [the docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_list_attributes) to see what is going on.

If you [inspect the source](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1446-1453) for this method, you'll find that it's actually using a custom template `single-product/product-attributes.php` to output this table you're seeing.

In order to change the output, you have two options:

1. [Override the template via your theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)
2. Observe `single-product/product-attributes.php` and use the information there to write your own custom loop in your original template.

The second option means that you'll likely use the [`get_attributes()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_attributes) method, instead of `list_attributes()`.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I use get_attributes() method